# Audio cracking with VLC and Bluetooth, but works with aplay

Tags: audio, bluetooth, alsa, pulseaudio

I'm trying to set up my Pi (v2) as a WiFi Hotspot and a Bluetooth Audio Module for my car.
The WiFi Hotspot works so far, but the sound over Bluetooth and VLC is only cracking.
When i use "aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav" i can hear the sound normally.
In the syslog i found the following:

```
Mar 10 13:07:05 raspberrypi pulseaudio[2516]: [pulseaudio] source.c: Default and alternate sample rates are the same.
Mar 10 13:07:10 raspberrypi kernel: [  875.550437] input: 44:74:6C:96:B0:ED as /devices/virtual/input/input2
Mar 10 13:07:11 raspberrypi pulseaudio[2516]: [pulseaudio] module-loopback.c: No such sink.
Mar 10 13:07:11 raspberrypi pulseaudio[2516]: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-loopback" (argument: "source=bluez_source.44_74_6C_96_B0_ED sink=alsa_output.platform-bcm2835_AUD0.0.analog-stereo rate=44100 adjust_time=0"): initialization failed.
```

I used [this tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Turn-your-Raspberry-Pi-into-a-Portable-Bluetooth-A/) to create the bluetooth hotspot, but i have no idea what the error message means and couldn't figure it out googling.
Any ideas from your side?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you handle powerup/down events? Do you just use USB, and let god sort it out for you?

Comment: I just use USB, nothing special.
It's not very good of course becaues when i turn on the car the power drops while the raspberry is booting up, you're probably best by just letting the power in the car for this outlet on all the time.

Comment: Pi’s audio jack is multipurpose and incredibly shitty for audio (pin usage affects it as well), use a USB dongle. Your method of supplying power will murder (at least) the microSD soon. Those in-car USB outlets are known to surge to 6-7v on power-up. You need a decent varistor, like this http://uk.farnell.com/bourns/cg0603mlc-05e/varistor-supp-esd-protect-20v/dp/1838966RL

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually working on streaming audio from my phone to my raspberry using the very same tutorial and having the similar problems.
I have no sound at all or only some low noise.

For now, I can only offer hints:

For one, this script /usr/lib/udev/bluetooth does not work. Pulseaudio can't do its job. I haven't found out exactly why but one reason to start with could be the name of the audiosink (as suggested in the syslog).
It's "alsa_output.0.analog-stereo" on my pi (check with pactl list sinks short).
And then I think amixer needs to be adressed with a "-c 0" for the card now:

```
amixer -c 0 set numid=3 1
amixer -c 0 set Master 100%
```

If you get any further please report back how to fix the tuturial.

Comment: *Pulseaudio can't do its job* is quite a blunt statement. I'm using it (also with bluetooth) and it works fine.